# Measure mass of an object only using gravitational force

Tags: newtonian-gravity, mass, measurements

Most if not all of our everyday methods of determining mass / weight work on the principle of normal force. The push provided to you by the surface which allows to sit/stand/lie down over it.The normal force however is electromagnetic in nature. Now my question is:

> Is there a way to determine mass of an object without involving EM force. If yes then what could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's *big* you can measure the orbital period of a body gravitationally bound to it. You can do this in principle for any size object, but only reasonably for something quite large.

If you assume you know the value of $G$, you can measure mass using a [Cavendish balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavendish_experiment). Usually we use that with known masses and measure the value of $G$ that way, but there's no reason you can't measure it the other way around. (This admittedly still uses electromagnetic forces, but in a different way.)